# Virtual audio sinks & settings gone after reboot

Tags: linux, fedora, pulse-audio, pipewire

I need some help on an issue that gives me headaches.
I'm running a F36 distro (Nobara) and was trying to create some virtual sinks via pulseaudio.Just like this:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink media.class=Audio/Sink sink_name=virtual-cable-a channel_map=surround-71
pactl load-module module-null-sink media.class=Audio/Sink sink_name=virtual-cable-games channel_map=surround-71
pactl load-module module-null-sink media.class=Audio/Sink sink_name=virtual-cable-multimedia channel_map=surround-71
pactl load-module module-null-sink media.class=Audio/Sink sink_name=virtual-cable-voice channel_map=surround-71
pactl load-module module-null-sink media.class=Audio/Source/Virtual sink_name=virtual-input-a channel_map=front-left,front-right
```

Working all good so far, was able to configure it quite well through Catia.
Which looks like this in the end:

[This is what i've set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2CAg.png)

Now when I reboot my system, all these settings are gone. I figured out that I (if I didn't miss something else) need to create the sinks at boot again, so they're available after login.
Unfortunately after a reboot all the settings are still lost. Is there a way to save these settings somehow?
Regards

Comment: I know nothing about `pactl`, but I know something about reading documentation. Start with `man pactl`, it says "`pactl` only exposes a subset […]. For the full set use the `pacmd(1)`. So you check `man 1 pacmd` and you learn it can be used to "enter the commands also understood in the `default.pa` configuration scripts; the manual also explicitly includes `default.pa(5)` in the "see also" section. Then you check `man 5 default.pa` and it seems this may be the right file. Can you take it form here?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `man 5 default.pa` unfortunately yields no result, just that there's no entry available.

Is there a way to get the current configuration into a default.pa-file?

Comment: Creating a `default.pa`, putting it under `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and have its content like this:

`load-module module-null-sink media.class=Audio/Sink sink_name=virtual-cable-a channel_map=surround-71` doesn't seem to work either. Am I missing something?

Comment: Still without experience (so it's not an answer), but let's try. In my Kubuntu `man 5 default.pa` states that for per-user mode `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` matters, and only if it doesn't exist then `/etc/pulse/default.pa`. For PulseAudio as a system service `/etc/pulse/system.pa`. The command to dump the current configuration seems to be `pactl dump` (`pactl dump > some_file` to dump to a file, but don't overwrite actual config files blindly). I totally don't know if/how Fedora is different in this matter. Any progress?

Comment: Well, it kinda is because it uses pipewire in the back. Maybe that's the reason. The only progess I've made so far is by still generating the virtual sinks for now and have Carla loaded with the correct setup/links, so I can at least automate it at boot and don't need to do anything else. A more permanent solution is still prefered, tho. But still thank you for your efforts.

Comment: A user on reddit pointed me in the right direction: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/wbge4s/comment/ii8orhp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 . Pipewire utilises other configuration files, so no wonder these settings never applied. Using this approach **so_then** suggested makes the sinks available at login.